# jquery to set td width in a nested table

Tags: jquery

I wanted to set the width of the td in a nested table, please help.

This is not working:

```
$('#WebPartWPQ7 table:eq(0) tbody tr td table tbody tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)')
    .css('width','30px');
```

---

```
<div id="webpartwpq7">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody> 
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                  this is the place I need to set width of the td tag
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>....</td>
              </tr>
              <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table>....
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: `$('#WebPartWPQ7 table:eq(0) tbody tr td table tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').css('width','30px');` I think you swapped the index for eq()

Comment: give it a id and use css id selector

Comment: You've chosen an unmaintainably complex selector for this. The slightest change in your markup will break it. As @Pilot said, give it an id, and it becomes this:

`$('td#foobar').css('width','30px');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are case-sensitive, so `WebPartWPQ7` needs to be `webpartwpq7`. Also, your `eq` numbers are wrong.

The selector should be:

```
$('#webpartwpq7 table:eq(0) tbody tr td table tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76hhU/2/

Comment: I have replace the tr:eq(0) td:eq(1), it is now working. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Give Id to the inner table as mentioned below :

```
<div id="webpartwpq7">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table id="innerTable">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>this is the place I need to set width of the td tag
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>....</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now you can assign width to the **TD** as shown below :

```
$('#innerTable tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').css('width', '30px');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the selector I used with the find method:

```
$('#webpartwpq7').find('table table tr td').eq(1)
```

You can verify you have the right one:

```
var myTest = $('#webpartwpq7').find('table table tr td').eq(1).text();
console.log(myTest); // output: this is the place I need to set width of the td tag
```